# Show that there is a one-to-one correspondence between $[0,1)$ and $T=\{$infinite strings of $0$s and $1$s$\}$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I have already showed that there is a one-to-one correspondence between $T$ and $P(\mathbb N)$. By Cantor's Theorem, I know that $P(\mathbb N)$ in uncountable and so $T$ must also be uncountable. Is it enough to show that $[0,1)$ is uncountable?

Comment: It is not enough to show that both sets are uncountable. (For example, take $\mathcal P(\Bbb R)$ and $\Bbb R$.) The idea will be to correspond a string $a_1,a_2,\ldots, $ in $T$ with the corresponding base-$2$ number $0.a_1a_2\ldots$, but you will need to take some care with non-unique decimal expressions of real numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most direct proof I know is:

- Create a map of $[0,1)$ into $T$ which assigns every number in $[0,1)$ the sequence of its digits in the *binary* representation. It is an injection, though not a surjection as those sequences of digits which have an infinite "tail" of ones ($11111\ldots$) are not in the range.
- Create a map of $T$ into a subset of $[0,1)$ using *ternary* representation. The range is the set of all numbers in $[0,1)$ which don't use the digit $2$ in the ternary representation. This is an injection of $T$ into $[0,1)$.
- Use Cantor-Schroder-Bernstein theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem)

Comment: I get how you came up with the first injection but what made you think to use ternary representation when constructing the map from $T$ to $[0,1)$?

Comment: @joseph I mean ... ternary ... or decimal ... doesn't really matter as long as we don't have problems with those pesky tails of 1's...

Answer (score 0):

You  still need to find a one-to-one correspondence between $T$ and $[1,0)$ in order to show that $[1,0) is uncountable.

You may consider the binary representation of  $x$ where $x\in [0,1)$ and try to define a bijection between $t$ and $[0,1)$